# IClassifierProvider is not getting initiated

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-package

I am trying to add color to the visual studio build output. So I am trying to get classifier of IClassifierProvider. But GetClassifier() is not getting called. What could be the problem? Source code sample is given below. When I am trying with VSColorOutput extension it getting initiated. Please tell me what i am missing?

```
 [ContentType("output")]
[Export(typeof(IClassifierProvider))]
public class OutputClassifierProvider : IClassifierProvider
{
    [Import]
    internal IClassificationTypeRegistryService ClassificationRegistry;

    [Import]
    internal SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

    public static OutputClassifier OutputClassifier { get; private set; }

    public IClassifier GetClassifier(ITextBuffer buffer)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("asd");
        try
        {
            if (OutputClassifier == null)
            {
                OutputClassifier = new OutputClassifier();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw;
        }
        return OutputClassifier;
    }
}
public class OutputClassifier: IClassifier
{
    public event EventHandler<ClassificationChangedEventArgs> ClassificationChanged;

    public IList<ClassificationSpan> GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan span)
    {
            return new List<ClassificationSpan>();
    }
}
```

Vsix manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
  <Identifier Id="3ac9d6e9-a3dc-4a27-a048-f4bb7fe5889b">
    <Name>Sample</Name>
    <Author>Company</Author>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">It conatains set of features which will ease the life of Atmel Studio user.</Description>
    <Locale>1033</Locale>
    <InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
    <SupportedProducts>      
      <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
    </SupportedProducts>
    <SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.0" MaxVersion="4.0" />
  </Identifier>
  <References>
    <Reference Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF" MinVersion="10.0">
      <Name>Visual Studio MPF</Name>
    </Reference>
  </References>

  <Content>
    <VsPackage>XFeatures.pkgdef</VsPackage>
  </Content>
</Vsix>
```

Comment: To rule a few things out, also include your .vsixmanifest.

Comment: I added the manifest content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Jason Malinowski I analyzed the manifest code and found MEF Content is missing there.
After adding MEF to content tag, it is working now.

```
 <Content>
    <VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|</VsPackage>
    <MefComponent>|%CurrentProject%|</MefComponent>
  </Content>
```

Comment: Which template did you start with?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski templeate is VSPackage.

Comment: If you were starting out with a new project, the Editor Classifier project would have been the best template to start with. But if you were adding this to an existing VSPackage project, then sadly there's no easy way to add it.

Comment: Yep. I am adding this to existing package. But it is working properly.
Thanks for your help.